# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll

Tags: php, sql-server, dll, sqlsrv

I'm hopelessly stuck on this: I'm trying to connect to MS SQL Server 2008 R2 with PHP, but I can't seem to get the configuration right.

```
Windows Server 2012 Standard
MS SQL Server 2008 R2

PHP:
Version: 5.4.31
Branch: HEAD
Build: C:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x86\obj\Release_TS
```

All I need is to call a PHP script from command line and save result to database. But I get following error:

```
C:\ankety>php uctenka.php 1012814411
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php-5.4.31-ts\ext\php_sqlsrv_54 in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php-5.4.31-ts\ext\php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\ankety\zpracuj.php on line 157
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\ankety\zpracuj.php on line 157
```

Now, of course there is correct version of `php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll` in correct folder (`C:\php-5.4.31-ts\ext\`). In `php.ini` I changed:

```
extension_dir = "C:\php-5.4.31-ts\ext\"
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

When I run the script it also says that `MSVCP100.dll` is missing on a computer, but it is in fact there - in `C:\Windows\System32` and I also tried `C:\php-5.4.31-ts\ext\` but without luck.

In `phpinfo()` there isn't loaded `sqlsrv` part.

I don't know where I could possibly went wrong, I searched this problem but none of those solutions worked. Hope someone has an idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those, who don't want to waste time as myself - try restarting the IIS server :-)